# linux command is not working in python subprocess

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am trying to scan all available wifi devices using python. I wrote below code to get SSID,BSSID and device information

```
results = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "nmcli", "-f", "SSID", "BSSID", "DEVICE", "dev", "wifi"])
```

But it is giving me error- "bssid not understood"

[image]

when I run the below command in terminal it is working fine.

```
sudo nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,DEVICE dev wifi
```

If I remove BSSID and DEVICE then it is working fine. And I am getting all the ssids

```
results = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "nmcli", "-f", "SSID",  "dev", "wifi"])
```

I could not understand what is going wrong.

I am using

```
Python-3.6.8
Ubuntu-18.04.2 LTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass the arguments as

```
["sudo", "nmcli", "-f", "SSID,BSSID,DEVICE",  "dev", "wifi"]
```

if the last command line really works. note that there is one argument `"SSID,BSSID,DEVICE"`.

you could also generate the list using [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#module-shlex):

```
import shlex

args = shlex.split("sudo nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,DEVICE dev wifi")
# ['sudo', 'nmcli', '-f', 'SSID,BSSID,DEVICE', 'dev', 'wifi']
```